# Receiving error "Block following 'let' is unfinished". expect an expression

Tags: f#

I am trying to run below F# code however getting error "Receiving error "Block following 'let' is unfinished". expect an expression". Any thought on this?    
    `let search func list =
let rec loop func list index =
match list with
| [] -> -1
| hd::tl -> if func hd then index
else loop func tl(index+1) loop func list 0`

Comment: Hard to tell, but i would guess the else isn't correctly indented.

Comment: You need to show your code as it is actual formatted in your source file. We can't say anything without seeing your indentation.

Comment: what is `tl(index+1)`? are you sure you didn't mean to index it: `tl.[index+1]`.

Comment: or maybe `tl (index+1)`?

Comment: Has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can paste a code block, so no need to format line by line. The error you see, is almost always comes from two (related) issues, a) the indent is off, b) either because the indent is off, or you just forgot to return a value from the function. This is rarely an issue because both VS and Code can use indent lines or depth colorization so you can immediately see what's off.

Did you mean something like this:

```
let search func list =
    let rec loop func list index =
        match list with
        | [] -> -1
        | hd::tl -> if (func hd) then index
                    else loop func tl (index+1)
    loop func list 0
```